# URL Rewriting in IIS7 annoyingly adds folder name to url

Tags: asp.net, .net, url, iis-7, url-rewriting

I'm having trouble with my URL Rewriting; IIS keeps adding the folder name to the url.

E.g. `my.site.com/Login/` gets re- written to `my.site.com/MY/Login`

The frustrating thing is that the `my.site.com/Login/`works but whenever a link is clicked it adds the `/MY/` to the url.

Does anyone know how to resolve this?

Existing re-write rule: `(http(s)?:\/\/)?my.site.com`

Rule I'm playing with (not finished) to try and detect the `/MY/` and redirect to the 'proper' url

```
(http(s)?://)?(www.)?my.site.com/MY/
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can you add your rewrite rules to your question to help diagnose the problem?

Comment: Where is this existing rule applied?